# Not all fields are fetched from table

Tags: cakephp, associations

I'm have a relationship setup between two tables (Contacts and Quotes) and I'm trying to access the information from Contacts Quotes Controller. So in QuoteController.php I have the following code:

```
 $contacts = $this->Quote->Contact->find('list', array('fields' => array(               
                    'Contact.id',
                    'Contact.name',
                    'Contact.company',              
                    'Contact.mainAddressLine2',
                    'Contact.mainAddressTown',
                    'Contact.mainAddressPostCode',
                    'Contact.mainAddressCountry'
            )));
            $this->set(compact('contacts'));

            echo '<pre>';
                print_r($contacts);
            echo '</pre>';
```

The output from the print_r statement is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Joe Bloggs
    [21] => Jane Doe
)
```

As you can see I'm only getting the id and name, for some reason the company, mainAddressLine2 etc are coming through in the array.

Ultimately I want the user to be able to select the Contacts name from a drop down list which will then, then details from the Contacts table will be populated in the Quotes view.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: btw `pr($contacts);` is a built in convenience function of php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->Quote->Contact->find('list',` will only render a 1d array, change it to `all` instead of `list`. You may also want to look into the [containable behaviors](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

btw `pr($contacts);` is a built in convenience function of php

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get all of the fields listed, why not use a find('all'). The find list, with 2 field params will return array with key->value while adding a 3rd field will group the results. see documentation on [find options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list)

```
$contacts = $this->Quote->Contact->find('all', array('fields' => array(               
                    'Contact.id',
                    'Contact.name',
                    'Contact.company',              
                    'Contact.mainAddressLine2',
                    'Contact.mainAddressTown',
                    'Contact.mainAddressPostCode',
                    'Contact.mainAddressCountry'
            )));
            $this->set(compact('contacts'));

            echo '<pre>';
                print_r($contacts);
            echo '</pre>';
```